# How to make a route in a Next.js app to return content from a different domain

Tags: reactjs, next.js, iframe, url-routing, app-router

For example, assume I have a Next.js app with the following routes:

1. `www.mydomain.com/`
2. `www.mydomain.com/route1`
3. `www.mydomain.com/route2`

Now if I try to navigate to `www.mydomain.com/route3`, Next.js will return a `404` error and the default "404 | This page could not be found" screen will be shown. Instead of this happening, I want to pull content (html/css/js) from another domain, e.g. `www.otherDomain.com` and show that on `www.mydomain.com/route3`.

Is this possible without iFraming  `www.otherDomain.com`?